# ERROR: check the manual [...] MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '

Tags: php, mysql, insert

So I have no idea what the deal is here... the following code below produces the mysql error following the code.

```
$fcontents = file("inventory.csv");

for ($i = 1; $i < sizeof($fcontents); $i++) { 
    $line = trim($fcontents[$i]);
    $arr = explode(',', $line);
    $values = implode(',', $arr);
    $values = str_replace('&', 'and', $values);

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO inventory (dealerid, name, vin, stock, newused, year, ' .
           'make, model, series, body, color, intcolor, price, retailprice, ' .
           'miles, transmission, engine, restraint, certified, photourl, ' .
           'comments, flag, options, citympg, hwympg) ' .
           'VALUES mysql_real_escape_string(' . $values . ')';
     mysql_query($sql);

     echo $sql.'<br><br>';
     if (mysql_error()) {
         echo mysql_error() .'<br><br>';
     }
}
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '

**RESOLVED!!!** So I wanted to post the solution to the stupid, dumb single quote, double quote glitch when dumping a .csv file in mysql... See below.:

```
$fcontents = file("http://pathtofile.com/inventory.csv"); for($i=1; $i < sizeof($fcontents); $i++) { $line = trim($fcontents[$i]); $arr = explode(",", $line); $arr = str_replace ("'","&#39;", $arr); $values = implode("','", $arr); $values = str_replace("\"',",'\'",', $values); $values = str_replace(",'\"",',"\'', $values); $values = str_replace("&", "and", $values); $sql = "INSERT INTO vehicles.inventory (dealerid,name,vin,stock,newused,year,make,model,series,body,color,intcolor,price,retailprice,miles,transmission,engine,restraint,certified,photourl,comments,flag,options,citympg,hwympg) VALUES ('".$values."')"; mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a PHP function in your MYSQL Query.

I don't believe you can just move the function outside of the quotes, but you have to loop through all values:

ie.

```
foreach($values as $key=>$value){
$values[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}
```

Add that to escape all of the values, then change your query to remove the PHP function.

Also, you have to implode with quotes as well, not just commas.

Comment: Well the above suggestions got rid of that error but now I'm getting this darn error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: As this page states (http://htmlfixit.com/cgi-tutes/tutorial_MySQL_Error_Invalid_Query_Column_Count_Does_Not_Match_Value_Count.php), the error is because you are specifying more columns than "VALUES". Make sure you are adding parenthesis when imploding the array.

Comment: Okay... this happens every day to all developers... I finally figured it out thru trial and error. It's always the dumbest, stuipdest thing. RE: Error - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1. The problem was when I imploded with '', the fields were putting the ' after the ""... so it looking like , '"entry', 'entry"' I love my job! :-)

Comment: Ok well when I manually put the single quote after the double quote it worked when I dumped it into the database! How would I force the single quote to be placed after a double quote in the .csv file if it found one???

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how your data is structured-- do you have a double quote inside of one of the values that is causing the problems? It sounds like you just want to do a str_replace to replace " with "'

Answer (score 1):

Between the `explode()` and `implode()` lines, you should be `mysql_real_escape_string()`-ing each of the values in `$arr`.  The function should be executed in PHP, not sent to MySQL for it to execute.

You could have printed out (or logged) your generated SQL statement and you would probably have spotted the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` is a PHP function, but you're still within string scope when it appears in  your code.

Try this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO inventory (dealerid, name, vin, stock, newused, year, make, model, series, body, color, intcolor, price, retailprice, miles, transmission, engine, restraint, certified, photourl, comments, flag, options, citympg, hwympg) VALUES (' . mysql_real_escape_string($values) .')';
```